# Пуктуация в предложениях со вставными конструкциями

Tags: пунктуация

Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, – какой ужас! – и руки бессильно опустились у него.

— запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения;

Тряский «автобус», а проще говоря, раздолбанный ЗИС-5 с огромной зеленой фанерной будкой вместо кузова, в которой были прорезаны по бокам два больших окна и вставлены стекла – вероятно, из разбитого троллейбуса, о чем свидетельствовал и десяток обшарпанных сидений, втиснутых в этот «салон», – натужно поскрипывая, вез Витьку Мальцева по утренней, еще припорошенной колючим снежком Москве.

но во втором примере нет запятой, закрывающей придаточное предложение.
Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что оно не закончилось. Вставная конструкция ( вероятно, из разбитого троллейбуса, о чем свидетельствовал и десяток обшарпанных сидений, втиснутых в этот «салон») входит в состав придаточного(поясняется, откуда стёкла), всё придаточное: в которой были прорезаны по бокам два больших окна и вставлены стекла – вероятно, из разбитого троллейбуса,..Но это придаточное является главным для следующего придаточного, в состав которого входит причастный оборот, его закрывает запятая перед тире.